# li menu tabs to fill the width of page (equally)

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to have a horizontal menu fill the width of the page or containing div. But i would like the `li` elements to all be the same width, now these are dynamic so the number of `li` elements can change page to page so i cannot simply set the width or split the percentage. I'm not sure I've got the right approach with the `table-cell`?

It's not a problem for the `li` elements to be stretched vertically, but they must all be stretch to the same amount.

Is there any way to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/juGJ4/

Comment: What if you did this in a Table with a single row `<tr>`, and had multiple data columns and you set the percentage on the columns like so `<td colspan="20%">`

Comment: The problem is the number of columns is not a constant as this menu system is used dynamically across the site for a number of pages with a differing number of navigation elements. Therefore i cannot use percentages or pixels.

Comment: You can do this, but not with pure CSS. By the way, you need a `table-row` element between your `table` and `table-cell` elements. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/juGJ4/1/

Comment: Pure CSS will not do the trick, you need to dial in a width based on the number of items in your menu.  You can try a JavaScript/jQuery aided solution or set up CSS rules (classes) that you can apply from the server if you are using a CSS or template system.

Comment: You can use javascript to get the number of child elements of the UL, then, give them all the same ID (different classes for styling purposes) and assign them each a % the is 100%/# of child element. IE 4 element = 25% width for all four.

Comment: @Jack the same ID? ID's must be unique.

Comment: Perfect, thank you all! Does anyone have any idea where to start with the JavaScript/jQuery solution? Edit: Also thanks for pointing out that `table-row` was missing @Blazemonger

Comment: @putvande Well, it may not be valid, but I don't like working in javascript using classes. You can have two elements with the same ID, it's just not valid, although it works in all browsers. But yes, IDs are *supposed* to be unique.

Comment: @giles if you're using jquery, just use the class, not the id. IDs are *supposed* to be unique, and it's better to be that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but not with pure CSS.

(By the way, you need a `table-row` element between your `table` and `table-cell` elements.)

Here's a solution that uses a single line of jQuery to specify the cell width after load: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/juGJ4/1/

jQuery:

```
$('.menu li').width((100/$('.menu li').length)+'%');
```

CSS:

```
div.width {
    display: table;
}
ul.menu, div.menu ul {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li, div.menu li {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In some cases, though, this still won't work, because your table cells contain long strings that won't wrap and therefore force their respective table cells to a certain minimum width. The best solution here is simply to break up those long strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a perfect solution. The only final problem i'm having is expanding the `a` element to fill the `li` in order for my colored corners to work. I would normally use `display:block` but this is not an option. @Blazemonger

Comment: You should move your colored corners to the `li` instead, and adjust your other styles as needed.

Comment: The `li` element colors the corner and the `a` element colors the tab, how would i adjust these, multiple backgrounds? @Blazemonger

Comment: You should post that as a separate question.

Comment: Agreed! Thank you so much for the Javascript fix.

Answer (score 0):

table-layout:fixed is supposed to do exactly what you want - make columns of equal width, if you are OK with using a table.

For the inline elements I found a neat trick with text-align:justify and extra empty content after:

```
    .fulljustify {
  text-align: justify;
}
.fulljustify:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```